# How to check AWS glue job status using python code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am referring below link to get job status. I don't want to create or start the job. I just want to know what to input in `get_job_run()` function. How to input job name and run id by hard coding without passing list?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-calling.html

Answer (score 0):

my bad, I got confused.

You will have to use cloudwatch events and then trigger lambda or sns topic. For more details you may check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/automating-awsglue-with-cloudwatch-events.html

`get_job_run()` needs jobid which you will get when you start job only. Alternatively you may use `get_job_runs()` (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.get_job_runs)

Comment: Please dont post code only answer, add some description to explain the context of how this answer helps to solve the problem in question

Comment: I want status of glue job not the crawler part.

Answer (score 0):

With `getResolvedOptions` you can retreive the jobID.

```
job = Context()
args = job.get_parameters()
job_run_id = args['JOB_RUN_ID']
```

And later use it with `get_job_run` method from boto3.

```
glue_status = boto3.client('glue')
response = glue_status.get_job_run(
    JobName='your_job_name',
    RunId=job_run_id,
    PredecessorsIncluded=False
)

print(response["JobRun"]["JobRunState"])
```